# Is there a way to get an email for all bug reports and feedbacks I receive for a published chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension published in chrome store. The problem is that I don't receive any emails or notifications for any feedbacks or bug reports users raise. Is there any option to enable them? The only way to find now is to manually check if there are any feedbacks or open bugs, which is very inefficient.

Comment: no way to do so. that part of the store is absurdly bad and seems pretty much abandoned. ive had issues some years old by now and still not fixed. that said, if you view the bugs/feedback from the store page inatead of the dev dashboard you might be able to find the user on google+ then hope that one in a thousand actually check their google+ notifications for your friend request, add you to hangouts and chat with them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web Store provides no way to access feedback (or reviews), with the exception of web scraping those pages.

Here's the (old) [feature request](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=295837) for this. It's in limbo for well over a year.